# How to take multiple photos in a sequence (1s delay each), using Swift on iOS8.1?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios-camera

I am trying to take few photos after a single user click on a Camera preview so I can present them and user can pick one that was timed best or use all in a "film strip" mode. The expected user experience is: "I open a camera, take a picture and then I see 5 pictures taken second by second. I do not have to press the 'take picture' button 5 times, one is just enough to start the sequence".

I am new to iOS and Swift and I base my work on a 'Swift Recipes' book (https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ios-8-swift/9781491908969/).

The source code to take a single photo is:

```
controller = UIImagePickerController()
    if let theController = controller{
        theController.sourceType = .Camera
        theController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as NSString]
        theController.allowsEditing = true
        theController.delegate = self
        presentViewController(theController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

plus the relevant image handling (via func imagePickerController). I tried playing with the controller objecct above, but miserably failed :( I believe that this is not the right way to get what I look for, but I struggle to find the right one. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there is a mode for this behavior in `UIImagePickerController`. If I were you I would use [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html) to implement this.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var connection: AVCaptureConnection!
    var output: AVCaptureStillImageOutput!
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    @IBOutlet var videPreviewView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.createCamera()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        self.videoPreviewLayer.bounds = self.videPreviewView.bounds
        self.videoPreviewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.videPreviewView.bounds), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.videPreviewView.bounds))
    }

    func createCamera() {
        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        if captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh) {
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
        } else {
            println("Error: Couldn't set preset = \(AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh)")
            return
        }

        let cameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        var error: NSError?
        let inputDevice = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(cameraDevice, error: &error) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
        if let error = error {
            println("Error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        if captureSession.canAddInput(inputDevice) {
            captureSession.addInput(inputDevice)
        } else {
            println("Error: Couldn't add input device")
            return
        }

        let imageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(imageOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(imageOutput)
        } else {
            println("Error: Couldn't add output")
            return
        }

        // Store imageOutput. We will need it to take photo
        self.output = imageOutput

        let connection = imageOutput.connections.first as AVCaptureConnection!
        // Store this connection in property. We will need it when we take image.
        self.connection = connection
        connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait

        captureSession.startRunning()

        // This will preview the camera
        let videoLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        videoLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

        self.videPreviewView.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

        // Store this layer instance in property. We will place it into a view
        self.videoPreviewLayer = videoLayer
    }

    func takePhoto(completion: (UIImage?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        self.output.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(self.connection) { buffer, error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(nil, error)
            } else {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
                completion(image, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is create an action that calls `takePhoto` with 3 times. You can use `NSTimer` to do this.

Comment: How to call takePhoto with UIButton?